# pandas count the number of value different from zero between two zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
0 0 0
1 0 0 
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 1
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
```

how do you get a dataframe which looks like this

```
0 0 0
4 0 0 
4 3 0
4 3 2
4 3 2
0 0 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 0 0
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What relationship links these two tables?

Comment: No description and no attempt.

Comment: no relationship. I am trying to set to zero if a group doesn't have enough observation

Comment: There has to be a relationship. Else the resultant df could be anything. Is it the number of "number-islands" column-wise? (I shouldn't have to reprimand you as you've already been here for 7 years but see [ask].)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need using for loop here , with `tranform`, and using `cumsum` create the key and assign the position back to your original df

```
for x in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[x]!=0,x]=df[x].groupby(df[x].eq(0).cumsum()[df[x]!=0]).transform('count')

df
Out[229]: 
     1    2    3
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  4.0  0.0  0.0
2  4.0  3.0  0.0
3  4.0  3.0  2.0
4  4.0  3.0  2.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  2.0  0.0
7  0.0  2.0  0.0
8  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Or without for loop

```
s=df.stack().sort_index(level=1)
s2=s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(1),s.eq(0).cumsum()]).transform('count').sub(1).unstack()
df=df.mask(df!=0).combine_first(s2)
df
Out[255]: 
     1    2    3
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  4.0  0.0  0.0
2  4.0  3.0  0.0
3  4.0  3.0  2.0
4  4.0  3.0  2.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  2.0  0.0
7  0.0  2.0  0.0
8  0.0  0.0  0.0
```