# How to apply a method to count the number of zero values between one values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54201640/8902456) is a similar answer to my question. However, I want to do all of it in an `apply` method and write a method for it.

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
data = {'username':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
                    'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b','b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
        'purchase_condition':[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                              0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['expected_results'] = [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

data looks like this:

```
     username  purchase_condition  expected_results
0         a                   0                 0
1         a                   0                 0
2         a                   0                 0
3         a                   1                 3
4         a                   0                 0
5         a                   0                 0
6         a                   1                 2
7         a                   0                 0
8         a                   0                 0
9         b                   0                 0
10        b                   0                 0
11        b                   0                 0
12        b                   0                 0
13        b                   1                 4
14        b                   1                 0
15        b                   1                 0
16        b                   0                 0
17        b                   0                 0
18        b                   1                 2
```

the `expected_results` column is created based on the following explanation:

For each `username`, For each row if `purchase_condition` is `1`, I count the number of `0`s between this row and the previous `1` and place that number for `expected_results` column.

For example,

1. In the 4th row (row# 3), `expected_results` is 3 because the first 3 rows' `purchase_condition` are `0`.
2. In the 7th row (row# 6), `expected_results` is 2 because there are 2 rows between row#6 and row#3 whose `purchase_condition` is `0`.
3. In the 15th row (row# 14), `expected_results` is 0 because although its `purchase_condition` is `1`, the previous row's (row# 13) `purchase_condition` value is `1` too.

Is it possible to do it in an `apply` method or should I use some kind of `cumsum`?

Comment: can you explain why 13th row `expected_result` is `4` instead of `6`

Comment: because its username is `b`. As I wrote in the question, I want these actions for each `username` to be done separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method `apply` are loops under the hood, so if possible, better is avoid it in pandas.

---

You can first compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) `(==)` for `m`, then get mask `m1` for first values of consecutive `True` and `False` of mask, get consecutive groups with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to `s`.

Last counts them by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and repeat by groups with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and set only for first `1` with chained both mask by `&` for bitwise AND in [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = data['purchase_condition'].eq(1)
m1 = m.ne(m.groupby(data['username']).shift())
s = m1.cumsum()
data['new'] = np.where(m1 & m, s.map(s.value_counts()).shift(), 0).astype(int)

print (data)
   username  purchase_condition  expected_results  new
0         a                   0                 0    0
1         a                   0                 0    0
2         a                   0                 0    0
3         a                   1                 3    3
4         a                   0                 0    0
5         a                   0                 0    0
6         a                   1                 2    2
7         a                   0                 0    0
8         a                   0                 0    0
9         b                   0                 0    0
10        b                   0                 0    0
11        b                   0                 0    0
12        b                   0                 0    0
13        b                   1                 4    4
14        b                   1                 0    0
15        b                   1                 0    0
16        b                   0                 0    0
17        b                   0                 0    0
18        b                   1                 2    2
```